# google maps SDK iOS remove pins with animation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there anyway to access `GMSMarkers` added to `GMSMapView`? Default `.clean()` method has no animation of removing object and I want to add some. Or should I override `clean()`?

Comment: you want to access markers for what ?

Comment: something like `marker.iconView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0,y: 0)`, `marker.map = nil` or `mapView.removeMarker...`

Comment: okay, so you need to access specific marker and when ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved my problem by storing `GMSMarkers` in an array and then manipulating with it.